# Is "digital dropshipping" legal?

Tags: united-states, is-x-legal, digital-content

For example, there is a game on Steam for $15 and my site would sell it for $20, but I don't actually own the game, just buy it from Steam and take the $5 profit. Is this legal? Also, if it is, how can I check if it's permitted by the original store's EULA? I'm not sure what term to even look for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this legal?

Generally yes, unless it unlawfully exceeds the scope of the license.

> Also, if it is, how can I check if it's permitted by the original
> store's EULA?

Read the whole EULA, focusing on terms related to resale, assignment, and transferability.